# selenium - browser opens and closes immediately

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am using maven to run some tests locally. Same code runs on my friends machine normally but on mine the browser opens and closes immediately with no errors. Tried looking online for some answers but didn't find anything useful. I think the issue is in the pom.xml file. Does any one have any idea how to fix it?

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>orbTesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>orbTesting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>orbTesting</name>
    <description>Selenium tests for orb</description>

    <properties>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0 </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
            <version>2.0rc2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <plugins>


            <!-- create a complete jar for testing in other environments -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>


                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                test.java.com.testsCases.TestRunnerTest
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>


                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>cucumber.api.cli.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>

                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <property>
                            <name>browser</name>
                            <value>${browser}</value>
                        </property>
<!--                        <property>-->
<!--                            <name>cloud_config</name>-->
<!--                            <value>${cloud_config}</value>-->
<!--                        </property>-->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>${env}</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- <parallel>methods</parallel> -->
                    <!-- <threadCount>4</threadCount> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                            <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
                            <buildNumber>${project.build}</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>true</parallelTesting>
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-report/${timestamp}</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-report/</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```